# Characteritic function convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\left\{[\frac{k}{2^{n}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n}}]:n\in\mathbb{N},k=0,...,2^{n}-1 \right\}=\left\{I_{n,k}:n\in\mathbb{N},k=0,...,2^{n}-1 \right\}$ and  $f_{n}(x)=X_{I_{n,k}}$ can someone help to prove that $f_{n}(x)$ converges in measure to zero.

The definition that we gave is that , if $\forall \epsilon>0,\delta>0$ there exists $n_{0}$ such that $\forall n\geq n_{0}$ ,$\mu(\left\{x:\left | f_{n}(x)-f(x) \right |\geq \epsilon \right\})<\delta$

Comment: I don't understand what $I_n$ is. Did you want to define $I_{n,k}=[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}]$ and show that $f_{n,k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$?

Comment: I think we have to handle it separately for each choice of k as $n\rightarrow \infty$ . For example to prove that for $k=0$ it converges in measure etc.

Comment: If $\epsilon > 1$, it's clear that  $\mu(\left\{x:\left | f_{n,k}(x) \right |\geq \epsilon \right\})=0$. If $0< \epsilon \le 1$, then  $\mu(\left\{x:\left | f_{n,k}(x) \right |\geq \epsilon \right\})=\mu ([\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}])=\frac{1}{2^n}$ which can be made as small as possible as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Search for the *typewriter function* as it's very similar to your $f_n$ and its an interesting counterexample to convergence in measure implies convergence almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition you gave of $f_n$ then the $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $| f_{n}(x)| > \epsilon $ are exactly the $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f_n(x) = 1$, as $Im(f_n) = \{0,1\}$. When is $f_n(x) = 1$? This happens only when $x \in I_{n,k}$. And the measure of an interval is the difference of the end points. In this case the measure of $I_{n,k}$ is $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Note that it is a decreasing sequence that tends to $0$. Knowing this you can make it arbitrarily small if you choose a certain $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{n_0}} < \epsilon$.